# Need help translating returned data in Oracle query

Tags: oracle, replace, translate

Please keep in mind I am building a query in two phases here.  The first phase is to get this to work with the existing query which is inefficient.

I am not good with PL/SQL at all, but I am learning slowly here.

I have this as a query:

```
SELECT LOGONID,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,ORGNAME
FROM WCSADMIN.USERREG UR,WCSADMIN.ADDRESS A 
WHERE UR.USERS_ID = A.MEMBER_ID
AND A.ADDRESSTYPE IN('S','SB') 
AND A.STATUS='P' 
AND UR.STATUS='1' 
AND (UPPER(LOGONID) LIKE UPPER('%cn=users%') 
OR UPPER(LOGONID) LIKE UPPER('%o=Buyer A Organization%'))
AND UPPER(LOGONID) LIKE UPPER('uid=resourcereaper%')
AND rownum < 10; -- limits the rows back
```

Essentially the LOGONID field holds the LDAP string for logging on.  The first characters in the field is uid=username,ou=......

I need to be able to carve that field down to just be "username".  I think you can use the translate command, but I am unsure about how to trim off the uid= and everything (including) the first ",".  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

- Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The translate command isn't the one you want - that does a character-for-character substitution.

You can use a combination of `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` to get the username, but the [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm) is a little cleaner (my opinion of course). This will give you the `uid` value:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(LogonID, '^uid=(.*?),.*$', '\1')
```

I'd explain the regular expression (and the `\1`) more, but I think the Oracle docs already do a much better job than I can.

Also, beware of the `WHERE ROWNUM < 10`. It's sometimes quirky (or at least appears so), and it won't work at all if you `ORDER BY` in your query. There's more info and a great explanation [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:948366252775). If you run into to trouble with `ROWNUM` you can fix it by putting `ROWNUM` into an outer query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT <your query>
) WHERE ROWNUM < 10
```

Comment: You sir are a gentleman and a scholar, thank you SO much for this!  It worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for!  +1 for the attention on the ROWNUM caveat!

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
substr(LOGONID,
       instr(LOGONID,'uid=')+4,
       instr(LOGONID,',')-instr(LOGONID,'uid=')-4
)
```

This relies on the fact that there's always 'uid=' and a comma somewhere after it. If it's not the case, you'll need to handle exceptional cases as well. You could also use REGEXP_SUBSTR() if you want to be fancy.

Comment: This was good, but I think using the REGEXP_REPLACE is actually cleaner.